# How To find Cross References(Internal Links) In Pdf File Using ItextSharp Lib

Tags: c#-4.0, itext

Hi I am using ItextSharp For searching Cross References(Internal Links) In pdf file. I already done with External Links.

Please Post If u have any solutions.

```
//Get the current page
PdfDictionary PageDictionary = R.GetPageN(page);

//Get all of the annotations for the current page
PdfArray Annots = PageDictionary.GetAsArray(PdfName.ANNOTS);

//Make sure we have something
if ((Annots == null) || (Annots.Length == 0))
// return null;
{

    Console.WriteLine("nothing");
}

//Loop through each annotation
if (Annots != null)
{

    foreach (PdfObject A in Annots.ArrayList)
    {
        //Convert the itext-specific object as a generic PDF object
        PdfDictionary AnnotationDictionary = (PdfDictionary)PdfReader.GetPdfObject(A);

        //Make sure this annotation has a link
        if (!AnnotationDictionary.Get(PdfName.SUBTYPE).Equals(PdfName.LINK))
            continue;

        //Make sure this annotation has an ACTION
        if (AnnotationDictionary.Get(PdfName.A) == null)
            continue;

        //Get the ACTION for the current annotation
        PdfDictionary AnnotationAction = AnnotationDictionary.GetAsDict(PdfName.A);
        //  PdfDictionary AnnotationAction = (PdfDictionary)AnnotationDictionary.Get(PdfName.A);

        //Test if it is a URI action (There are tons of other types of actions, some of which might mimic URI, such as JavaScript, but those need to be handled seperately)
        if (AnnotationAction.Get(PdfName.S).Equals(PdfName.URI))
        {
            PdfString Destination = AnnotationAction.GetAsString(PdfName.URI);

            string url1 = Destination.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us how you've found external links and we'll show you have to find internal links. (There's only a small difference.) Expect other comments asking **What have you tried so far?**

Comment: Hi Bruno please check i updated code

Comment: OK, you're already very close to the solution. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You've already done most of the work. Please take a look at the following screen shot:

[image]

You see the `/Annots` array of a page. You are already parsing that array in your code and you skip all annotations that aren't of the `/Subtype` `/Link` or don't have an `/A` key, which is excellent.

Currently you're only looking for values of `/S` that are of type `/URI`. You *say* you're already done with external links, but that's not true: you should also lok for entries where `/S` is `/GoToR` (remote goto). If you want internal links, you need to look for `/S` values equal to `/GoTo`, `/GoToE`, and (in the future) `/GoToDp`. Maybe you also want to remove the `/JavaScript` actions, because they can also be used to jump to a specific page.

Please download [The ABC of PDF](https://leanpub.com/itext_pdfabc/) and take a look at table 3.11 for more info. (The book is available for free.)

Comment: Hi Bruno You Mean to say I need to change here as i changed but its not giving Internal Links(Cross References) Please help             "if (AnnotationAction.Get(PdfName.S).Equals(PdfName.GOTOE))
{
PdfString Destination1 = AnnotationAction.GetAsString(PdfName.GOTOE);"

Comment: Show us the PDF. Note that you only mention `GoToE` in your comment. That's a link to an embedded file and you won't find many PDFs that have them. You'll find more internal links that have `/GoTo` as value for the `/S` entry. Didn't you read table 3.11 of my book?

Comment: Bruno i read book and but when i mentioned (pdfName.s)equals(pdfname.goto) but i am unable find any internal links can u please hehp me with some code.

Comment: I can't help you if you don't share the PDF. For instance: maybe the internal link is created using JavaScript (as explained in my answer). Did you take a look at your file using RUPS (the tool I used to take the screen shot)?

Comment: I don't share my mail on StackOverflow, nor should you (and you shouldn't shout either). If you want to contact somebody at iText, go to their web site: http://itextpdf.com/support

Comment: Somebody flagged your comment and removed it because you shouldn't share your mail. I won't mail you either. Follow the rules please!

Comment: ok Bruno, as i checked java script links is not in pdf file, how can i share pdf to you & is their any method to get all links even they javascript also.

Comment: Bruno Ok I don't want java script internal links can u please write one or two of code for me?

Comment: First you say there are no JavaScript links, now you ask me to write one or two of code for you because you don't want JavaScript. That doesn't make sense! Is there JavaScript in your PDF or isn't there? Note that StackOverflow isn't here to do your work in your place. I'll write you some code (1) if I feel like writing code or (2) if you have a support contract for us. If you have a support contract, you know how to reach us: http://itextpdf.com/sales